# Как на SEO продвижение сайта повлияет замена файлов на хостинге?

Tags: html, seo, продвижение

Доброго времени суток, суть такая: Создал сайт, загрузил его на хостинг и начал продвигать, скажем через месяц, я решил кое-что поменять на сайте, не только сам контент но и структуру сайта (не кардинально, а по-немногу) и как итог, окажет ли периодическое изменение файлов сайта на его продвижение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря какие изменения были проведены.
 Если предположим у вас был сайт без категорий, а вы взяли и добавили категории на сайт да не просто добавили а еще и написали туда SEO текстов, заголовков да еще и сделали это в соответствии с рекомендациями по SEO то есть соблюли семантическое ядро и  тд и тп, то само собой ваш сайт так или иначе поднимется в выдаче.
справедливо и обратное..
а если вы спрашиваете изменится ли выдача от того что вы файл file.php переместили из папки в папку, то нет в прямую не повлияет.

Поисковики при индексации сайта обращают внимание только на фронтенд, то есть на уже выход сайта ( валидную верстку, разметку и тд и тп).
бекэнд влияет косвенно (время загрузки страницы, наличие либо отсутствие бессмысленных редиректов, вирусов, вредоносного кода)